# How to start multiple containers that use tcp with Docker

Tags: docker, tcp, port, docker-container

I'm trying to run a second Meteor app in a Docker's container. The first (who is running as I want) is accessible with `localhost:3000`and I want to run a second one in a other port like `localhost:3003`. When I try to access the second I got this

> This website is not accessible. Localhost don't allow the connexion. Do a research about localhost 3003 on Google.

And If I look into Docker I can see that my containers are running:
[image]
but I noticed a difference between the port, the one who is accessible is `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`and the one who isn't accessible is `3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3003->3003/tcp`so I think there is something wrong here.

And in my docker-compose.yml I did :

```
app:
  image: jeromevi/controlcontainersapp
  ports:
    - "3003:3003"
  environment:
    - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3003
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
```

Thank you for the help

[EDIT] there are the logs :

```
=> Starting app on port 3000...

/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                        throw(ex);
                        ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect
    at Object.Future.wait (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:219:27)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:103:40)
    at meteorInstall.both.collections.infosContainers.js (both/collections/infosContainers.js:2:14)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:106:16)
    at /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/app/app.js:217:1
    - - - - -
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

[EDIT2] With the new config the errors are : 
[image]

But I have the network testNtw:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
6767c4bf208f        bridge              bridge              local
c69fbc3a59cf        host                host                local
f6f5083df32e        none                null                local
3d0aacdbb757        testNtw             bridge              local
```

And I did the same docker-compose.yml as in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo docker network create <your network name>
```

Docker Compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: jeromevi/controlcontainersapp
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
    environment:
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
    networks:
      - <your network name>
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - <your network name>
networks:
  <your network name>:
    external: true
```

Then check this url in your browser:

```
http://localhost:3003
```

**Clarification**:

With default networking you need to use `links` that is a legacy feature. I recommend using `User-Defined` networks. `User-Defined` networks provide   built in `DNS` so you can connect to your containers from other containers on the same `User-Defined` network by `name`. In your case a container named `mongo` needs to be accessed from a container named `app`.

Comment: After like 3 second the ports has disappeared and I can't access obviously

Comment: `docker logs  <container id>` and post the output, for app container obviously

Comment: (Sorry I didn't know that the word "obviously" had a bad meaning in English...) I have posted the logs and thank you for the help

Comment: I got an error: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for app: 'networks'`

Comment: And I think an other thing is false, I can't use the port 3000 because my first app (who is running) is on the port 3000 accessible via localhost:3000

Comment: port 3003 on your host (free) is getting bind to port 3000 in the container (free), check my updated answer please.

Comment: I still have some errors with the network look the Edit

Comment: `docker-compose --version` and did you add `version: '2'` add to the top of `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: My bad I did a miss typing ! Now it's working ! Thank you for the help !

Comment: No problem, added clarification, In case you are wondering why user defined networks fixed the problem.